# Value isn't incrementing properly

Tags: c++

The purpose of this application is to simulate numerous games of craps. I have another version where it plays one game, asks for user input and outputs information. The purpose of this version is to only display the results after 10,000 games. The results being how many games the house won, how many games the player won and the average number of rolls per game. I have not implemented to rolls yet as I wanted to get the games won incrementing properly first.

What happens when I execute this is a wall of numbers (this is due to cout << playerwintotal;) and is on purpose, but the numbers are duplicating 3-4 times, until the loop has exectued 10,000 times.

ie. 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5, etc

The end result usually turns out something like this:

After 10,000 games of craps:
Player won 2502 games.
The house won 3625 games.

I'm not really sure how to fix this, as far as I can tell everything is as it should be, although this is only my 4th day of C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "randgen.h"

using namespace std;

const int MAX_PLAYS = 10000;

int main() {

    int roll;
    RandGen rg;
    int die1 = rg(6) + 1;
    int die2 = rg(6) + 1;
    int point;
    int total = die1 + die2;
    bool playerwin;
    bool housewin;
    int playerwintotal = 0;
    int housewintotal = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PLAYS; ++i) {
        roll = 1;

        if (roll == 1 && (total == 7 || total == 11)) {
            playerwin = true;
            ++playerwintotal;
        }
        if (roll == 1 && (total == 2 || total == 3 || total == 12)) {
            housewin = true;
            ++housewintotal;
        }
        if (roll == 1 && (total != 2 || total != 3 || total != 12)) {
            point = total;
            playerwin = false;
            housewin = false;
        }

        die1 = rg(6) + 1;
        die2 = rg(6) + 1;
        total = die1 + die2;
        ++roll;
        if (total == point) {
            playerwin = true;
            ++playerwintotal;
        }
        if (total == 7) {
            housewin = true;
            ++housewintotal;
        }

        cout << playerwintotal;

    }
    cout << "After " << MAX_PLAYS << " games of craps:\n" << "Player won "
            << playerwintotal << " times\n" << "The house won " << housewintotal
            << " times\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code would be soooo much easier to read if you fixed your indentation.

Comment: Also you might want to look at simplifying your if logic by having a single `if (roll == 1)` statement and the use of the `else` keyword.

Answer (score 5):

```
total != 2 || total != 3 || total != 12
```

is always true. You probably meant

```
total != 2 && total != 3 && total != 12
```

Comment: But wouldn't &&ing it mean all three values must be true in order for the body to execute?

Comment: @AndrewB Yes. However, every number is either not equal to 2, not equal to 3, or not equal to 12.

Comment: All right well I'll give that a shot when I can get a similar version of visual studio on my home computer that I use on my school computer

Answer (score 4):

The numbers are repeating, because when the house wins or noone wins, the `playerwintotal` is unchanged and therefore repeats. Perhaps you meant to do:

```
cout << "Turn: " << i+1 << " Player wins: " << playerwintotal << ' ';
```

Also, as Sebastian pointed out in his answer, or'ing nots is not such a good idea, so make sure you give him an upvote.

Comment: But there is always a win, it's always going to be the house or the player. The program is only meant to display the results at the end of the 10,000 games. So when the for loop has completed it displays how many times the house and the player won in those 10,000 games. There is never not a win, which is something that has been ensured in the original game.

Answer (score 1):

> but the numbers are duplicating 3-4 times

They should be - you don't print the number of the current game, but the times your player has won (he doesn't every time).